# How to remove collection of nested table using EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on an application where there are many table linked with each other I want to remove the collection related with sub nested table Here is the implementation I have added but I am in search of better approach as I don't think this is the best one. Here is my code

```cs
public async Task AddUpdateProjectCosting(string userId, ProjectCostingDTO model)
{
    var estimate = await GetAll().Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true)
            .Include(x => x.CustomerAddress)
            .Include(x => x.TaxEntity)
            .Include(x => x.ProjectAddress)
            .Include(x => x.CustomerBillingAddress)
            .Include(x => x.CompanyAddress)
            .Include(x => x.AdditionalExpenses)
            .Include(x => x.EstimateDetails.Where(d => d.IsDeleted != true))
            .ThenInclude(x => x.EstimateDetailsSections.Where(s => s.IsDeleted != true))
            .ThenInclude(x => x.EstimateCostLineItems.Where(c => c.IsDeleted != true))
            .ThenInclude(x => x.TaxEntity).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (estimate != null)
    {
        estimate.UpdatedBy = userId;
        estimate.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        estimate.OverHeadPercentage = model.OverHeadPercent;

        
        foreach (var item in estimate.EstimateDetails)
        {
            if(item.EstimateDetailsSections.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var detail in item.EstimateDetailsSections)
                {
                    if(detail.EstimateCostLineItems.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var costLine in detail.EstimateCostLineItems)
                        {
                            if (costLine.AdditionalExpenses.Count() > 0) // remove this additional expense....
                                costLine.AdditionalExpenses = new List<AdditionalExpense>(); /// Here is the additiona expense exists in EstimateCostLine table
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        await Change(estimate);
    }
}
```

Here I am getting estimate record which I need to update it as well that is why I am using **Include** and **ThenInclude**. There is a collection inside EstimateCostLineItem which I want to remove and add new collection. How can I achieve this by using best approach.

Comment: Other includes also needed?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I am afraid Yes otherwise it will update other entities with empty records

Comment: The functionality here is working fine but what bother me a lot the multiple foreach and it will slow down my process

Comment: Actually no. Load only needed things.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv but for **additionalExpense** still we must added **thenIncludes** and for that I can't see any other way to implement multiple **foreach** which I don't want to

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do not load properties which is not used for `Update`. Also removing items can improved by selecting from database only needed data:

```cs
public async Task AddUpdateProjectCosting(string userId, ProjectCostingDTO model)
{
    var estimate = await GetAll()
        // why there is no appropriate filter?
        .Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (estimate != null)
    {
        estimate.UpdatedBy = userId;
        estimate.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        estimate.OverHeadPercentage = model.OverHeadPercent;

        // filter from child to parent
        // Correct with actual navigation properties

        var toRemove = await context.AdditionalExpenses
            .Where(a => a.EstimateCostLineItem.EstimateDetailsSection.EstimateDetail.Estimate.Id == estimate.Id)
            .ToListAsync();

        context.AdditionalExpenses.RemoveRange(toRemove);

        await Change(estimate);
    }
}
```

Comment: These additionalExpenses are against **EstimateCostLineItem** not **Estimate**. If you go through my query I have added multiple **foreach** just to go deep down to get the list of additionalExpenses against **EstimateCostLineItem**

Comment: If you want clear answer post your model.

Comment: My model are basically clear as I am loading straight **EstimateEntity** with navigation properties using **inlcude** and **ThenInclude**

Comment: How you define parent entity? For example navigation from `EstimateCostLineItem` to `EstimateDetailsSection`.

Comment: **EstimateDetailsSection** contains multiple **EstimateCostLineItem**. They have to many relation.